# get value of Checkbox in datagrid

Tags: windows, vb.net, datagrid

I am working with windows application.
I have a datagrid in vb.net. Its first column is a checkbox. I want to know which checkboxes are checked and which are not.
My code is :

```
         Dim dr As DataGridViewRow
            For i = 0 To gdStudInfo.RowCount - 1
                dr = gdStudInfo.Rows(i)
                att = dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                If att.Equals("Present") Then
                    qry = "insert into Stu_Att_Detail values(" & id & "," & gdStudInfo.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString() & ",'" & dr.Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "')"
                    con.MyQuery(qry)
                End If
            Next
```

I am getting correct values for all checked check box, but it gets error when the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: If Draak's answer works, is it possible that you have some code similar to `Column1.FalseValue = Nothing` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you try this?

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Cells(0).Value) Then
   'do stuff here
End If
```

Comment: Yes, This was the problem that unchecked checkboxes where giving null value. But If I want that at the filling time all checkboxes should be by default checked then what should I do?